# File exists but isn't found (Python)

Tags: python

There's a network drive that holds a bunch of drawings stored as 'part number'.pdf files. I'm trying to copy each of those files to a new directory and rename them to 'reference ID'.pdf. When I run this method, it logs 'File Not Found' on every file (there's over 7000 in the folder) even though they are there. I'm guessing this has something to do with a path error, but I'm pretty new to python so I can't seem to track it down. If someone could take a look at my code I would greatly appreciate it! I'm using python 3.6 if that makes any difference.

```
def convert_files(self):

    # Directory that holds the drawings files
    drawings_file_path = '\\\\BILBO\\Engineering\\drawings\\approved drawings'

    # Open the file that associates part numbers with reference IDs
    with open('part_reference_list.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        line_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in line_reader:

            # Read the part number and reference ID from the reference list
            logging.debug("Reading row {} from part reference list...".format(row))

            # Store the part number and reference ID
            # Truncates unused characters from the part number
            part_number = row[0][3:11]
            ref_ID = row[1]

            try:
                logging.debug("Searching for {}...".format(part_number))

                # Set the source and destination paths
                # and copy the .pdf to the new diretory
                dest_file_name = '{}\\{}.pdf'.format(self.file_path, ref_ID)
                src_file_name = '{}\\{}.pdf'.format(drawings_file_path, part_number)
                copyfile(src_file_name, dest_file_name)

                logging.info("Copied {}.pdf to {}.pdf".format(part_number, ref_ID))

            except FileNotFoundError:
                logging.warning("Drawing file for part: {} was not found.".format(part_number))
```

Comment: hi @a.sapp, it seems quite a more than usual numbers of `\` in your path...

Comment: What do you pass to this function as its argument? More precisely, what is  `self.file_path` value in the function?

Comment: Convert \\ to / in your path specs.

Comment: self.file_path is a user defined directory that is set through a dialogue box before this function is called. Nothing is passed to this function.

Comment: @Shiva that won't change anything.

Comment: @Shiva, I've tried that and I get the same result. That's how I had them to begin with, but figured it was worth trying this way to see if it would work.

Comment: @a.sapp Betcha anything the user-defined directory is a relative path, not an absolute one. Python is looking for that directory RELATIVE to its current working directory, and finding nothing.

Comment: Well, the other thing is there's a space in your `drawings_file_path`.

Comment: @Shiva what OS are you working on that doesn't allow spaces in filepaths?

Comment: I mean it needs to be escaped, doesn't it?

Comment: @Shiva No, only if you're working in the shell directly (since most shells will split on spaces). Python's `copyfile` is a bit too robust for that.

Comment: @Adam Smith, I'm using self.file_path.set(filedialog.askdirectory()) to set the path. Would this be an absolute path or relative?

Comment: @a.sapp depends on what `filedialog.askdirectory()` returns, but given the behavior you're experiencing, I'm gonna say it gives a relative directory. It's probably worth tossing a `print(self.file_path)` in the function you posted so you can diagnose more easily.

Comment: @Shiva (you're right, though, that in the shell `$ cp somefilewith spaces someotherfile` must be escaped to `$ cp somefilewith\ spaces someotherfile`. Even on Windows, though it uses a different escape `> copy somefilewith^ spaces someotherfile`)

Comment: @Adam Smith, it's printing PY_VAR0

Comment: @AdamSmith, or `copy "somefilewith spaces" someotherfile` :]

Comment: @a.sapp well where's the `PY_VAR0` folder? Presumably not in your `C:\Users\a.sapp` folder (or wherever the working directory is)

Comment: @Adam Smith, no clue where it is. It is that line that's causing the issue. I hard coded the absolute path in and it works fine now! I guess I'll have to play around with that and see what I can figure out. Thanks for the help!